# How to change content in the same form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I need  to view new content in the same form (not to open a new form) when I click some button.
For exapmle this opera installer. When I click ["Options"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lLZ3.png) content changes in this window. And when I click ["Back"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oAGU.png) I see previous components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is different ways to achive this easily :

You can use the [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) control, which holds different pages you can design separatly in the vs designer.
Then you choose the initial one, hide the tabs selection bar on top, and control the **TabPage** selection with your buttons with *SelectedTab* or *SelectedIndex* properties.

Or you can simply wrap each section in a [GroupBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control, set them all to *Visible=false* except the initial one and handle their visibility with your buttons with something like :

```
List<GroupBox> sections = new List<GroupBox>() { /* add your sections */ };

nextButton.OnClick += (o, e) =>
{
    sections.ForEach(s => s.Visible = .../* condition to select the section you want displayed and hide others */);
};
```